# Save a result from a mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, save, var, export-to-csv

I write this in the shell of mongo (line by line). When I write "documentos", the results are displayed in the shell of mongo.

> var ZZZ = db.mycollection.distinct( 'name', { event: 'a' } );
>
> var documentos = db.mycollection.find({ nombre: { $in: ZZZ }});
>
> documentos

How can I to create a collection from that query? or.. "save" or "export" the result?
Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Execute the below script in the shell

```
var ZZZ = db.mycollection.distinct("name", {"event": "a"} );
db.mycollection.find({"nombre":{$in:ZZZ}}).forEach(
function(doc){db.newcollection.insert(doc);}
)
```

It will iterate each document and insert the documents into a new collection.

Comment: Yeahhhhh!!!!! Thank you so much (thank you both). BatScream, your script works perfectly :))))))) really... thx you are a genius

Answer (score 0):

Querying the companies collection and inserting the result in new collection.
newCollection doesn't exists.
Here is how mongo shell looks like

```
 x = db.companies.findOne();
 db.newCollection.insert(x);

WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

You can export using

```
mongoexport --db companies --collection companies --csv --fieldFile D:\fields.txt --out D:\company.csv
```

where fields.txt contains contains a line-separated list of fields to export.

### Modified

```
> cities = db.zips.distinct("city", {pop:{$gt: 81000}} ); n = db.zips.findOne({c
ity :{$in: cities}});db.newCollection.insert(n);
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

Comment: thx! but... I already tried it and this error message appears:  can't save a DBQuery object at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:143 I write this: > var zzz = db.EJEMPLO.distinct( 'id', { evento: 'a' } ); >var documentos = db.EJEMPLO.find({ id: { $in: zzz }}); > db.newCollection.insert(documentos);

Comment: Are you trying this in mongoShell ?

Comment: Yes. I use mongoShell (mongo 2.6.4).

Comment: my database is very very large. Then, I need to make a filter (like query) and export to csv or save in a new collection. I don't know do this differently...

Comment: The commands should be given in the same line and to be executed together                                                             x = db.companies.findOne(); db.newCollection.insert(x);

Comment: Thx Abhi.... but I already tried it:                                              >zzz = db.EJEMPLO.distinct( 'id', { evento: 'a' } );      >documentos = db.EJEMPLO.find({ id: { $in: zzz }});        >db.NewCollection.insert(documentos);                               not working :(                                                  If I only write                                        >documentos = db.EJEMPLO.find();        >db.NewCollection.insert(documentos);                           I cannot do my query filter...